# passing parameters to template helpers

Tags: meteor

In Discover Meteor, there's a point where we pass a parameter (`title` or `url`) to a template helper like this:

```
<div class="form-group {{errorClass 'title'}}">
...
...
<div class="form-group {{errorClass 'url'}}">
```

Then we define helpers that are aware of the parameter being passed, like this:

```
errorClass: function (field) {
  return !!Session.get('postSubmitErrors')[field] ? 'has-error' : '';
}
```

The `Session.get('key')[parameter]`syntax is confusing to me - why is the parameter not passed with the key, but outside the function, surrounded by brackets? I don't see examples of this syntax in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in JavaScript we can access properties of an object like this:

```
foo.bar
```

This means:

1. get the object in the variable `foo`
2. extract the property called `bar`.

There exists an alternative syntax:

```
foo["bar"]
```

This means exactly<sup>1</sup> the same.

Why do we need this alternative syntax? Well, it allows us to do cool things like this:

```
var foo = { bar: "Nero", baz: "Caligula"}
var field = "bar";
foo[field]; // Evaluates to "Nero"
field = "baz";
foo[field]; // Evaluates to "Caligula"
```

(and it is how indexing into an array works).

This can be easily extended to:

```
function accessFoo(field) {
    return foo[field]; // with foo from previous example.
}
accessFoo("bar"); // evaluates to "Nero"
accessFoo("baz"); // evaluates to "Caligula"
```

I hope you can see the similarity of your code sample and my last example.

<sup>1: for practical purposes - maybe there are some slight differences. If so, I'd love to hear about them in the comments.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I totally missed that this might be bracket-notation. But since the `Session.get` is returning an object, it makes total sense.